# Bridged Network in VirtualBox cannot ping host OS to guest OS while everything else works well

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, bridge, wanem

VirtualBox 5.0.4 on Windows 10 Enterprise (host) in LAN. Launching VM from live image of WANem - a network simulator over Knoppix Linux.

Changed Network Adapter to “Bridged Adapter” of my single connected NIC (I have two but the second one is disconnected). Host NIC is DHCP-enabled. Host firewall turned off. The single NIC in guest is DHCP-enabled.

Guest can access Internet and ping other PCs in LAN. Other PCs in LAN can ping guest.

The problem: Host OS cannot ping guest OS, guest OS cannot ping host OS.

The ultimate goal is to route traffic from host to PC1 via guest OS.

I read tons of info and tried turning off DHCP on host and guest NICs as well as “VirtualBox Host-Only Network” virtual NIC [as was suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11177901/453271).

The only way I managed to ping host OS to guest OS was two NICs on guest OS; one “Host-Only” (for host OS to guest OS) and another NAT (for guest OS to host OS). It doesn’t work for me because routing and simulation become much more complicated in case of 2 NICs or I just don’t know how to configure them properly.

Comment: I had this problem a few years ago and got it working by bridging between the NIC on the host and the VB adapter in host-only mode. However I was using fixed IP addresses so may not help you. See here for details: http://superuser.com/a/514761/18735